# Integral of inverse of square root of a quadratic

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I haven't taken a course on calculus so far so I don't know what to do. The integral may be wrong. Please tell me which part of it is wrong.
$$
q∫_{+a}^{-a}\lim_{c \to g}\frac 1{(b^2+c^2)^{3⁄2}} dc
$$
All letters in the problem are variables.

Since the question can't be understood. Here is the figure of the main context:
[image]

b: radius of the cylinder

+a and -a: the x component of the cylinder's corners' positon vectors

Actually this is an electrostatic problem. I am trying to find the electric field due to a tube applied on a point. Since the tube is infinite number of rings, I first found the electric field of a ring which is

$E=kcq/(c^2+b^2)^{(3⁄2)}$
where k=8,98... is Coulomb's constant and q is the charge of an infinitesmal ring. And g is the distance between the point and the +a.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Fabian I want the integral to disappear if it is the correct term for it. I mean I want to solve the integral for these variables.

Comment: How can we know which part is wrong? you've just written some integral! Are you asking whether you can take the limit first and then integrate or?

Comment: What's that? Replace $c$ by $g$, than you need to only integrate a constant. The question is malformed, btw.

Comment: @Phonon First of all please calm down. It is for a physics project not a random integral and I know it is hard to understand the problem since I have lack of knowledge about calculus. I am just asking how to solve this integral. I think limit should be taken first.

Comment: @Starior Provide a physical context of problem. That would be more useful than the pointless $a$, $b$, $c$, $g$ and $q$.

Comment: @m0nhawk Okay thank you for the suggestion. I hope that provides the necessary information you need.

Comment: Do you want the electric field in the center of the tube?

Comment: @Fabian No I want to calculate the electric field which the whole tube creates on the point outside the tube. I found the electric field which one ring creates on the point and I am trying to derive the whole tube's electric field since the tube is made out of infinite infinitesmal rings.

Comment: @Starior Use Gauss law for this.

Comment: @m0nhawk I can't use Gauss' law because Gauss law can only be used for calculating the electric field which is perpendicular to the surface. However, I am trying to calculate the electric field on a point which is along the axis of the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ring, with a center in $(0,0,0)$. And on the point on the axis it has induce the electric field:

$$
E = \frac{q z}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 (r^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}
$$
where, $r$ is a ring radius and $z$ is a distance from origin, so, point have coordinates $(0,0,z)$.

Then, if you move the ring by some factor $\delta$ it become and $\delta$ would be between $-a$ and $a$:

$$
E = \frac{q (z + \delta)}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 (r^2 + (z+\delta)^2)^{3/2}}
$$

Now, it's only needed to integrate this by $\delta$ from $-a$ to $a$:

$$
E = \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{q (z + \delta)}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 (r^2 + (z+\delta)^2)^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}\delta = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{z+\delta}{(r^2 + (z+\delta)^2)^{3/2}}
$$

Integrating this:

$$
E = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + (z-a)^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + (z+a)^2}}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you please clarify what z is again?

Comment: @Starior I used the cylindric coordinates, where $z$ is a line of symmetric of this rings.

Comment: So is $(z-a)$ the distance between the point and -a whereas $(z+a)$ the distance between the point and +a in my figure?

Comment: @Starior Yes. I used $+\delta$.

Comment: @monhawk I also made an equation which is $kq\sum_{d=x}^y \frac {d^2} {{(r^2+d^2)}^{3/2}}$ where x is the distance between the point and +a, y is the distance between the point and -a in my figure, r is the radius of tube and d is the variable distance between the point and the centres of the rings. Since we can think the tube as unlimited number of infinitesmal rings we can calculate the electric field due to  tube by summing the electric field of each ring. Am I right? However, when I give values to variables, the answers to your equation and my equation are different. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @Starior Because there are infinitely, but uncountable set of rings; and sum can only been used on a countable set of rings.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for every $(b,g)\ne(0,0)$,
$$
\lim_{c \to g}\frac 1{(b^2+c^2)^{3⁄2}}=\frac 1{(b^2+g^2)^{3⁄2}}
$$ 
hence
$$
I=q∫_{+a}^{-a}\lim_{c \to g}\frac 1{(b^2+c^2)^{3⁄2}} dc,$$ is $$I=q∫_{+a}^{-a}\frac 1{(b^2+g^2)^{3⁄2}} dc=\frac q{(b^2+g^2)^{3⁄2}}∫_{+a}^{-a} dc=\frac{-2aq}{(b^2+g^2)^{3⁄2}}.
$$

Comment: ...Expanding @monhawk's first comment, quite fitting but seemingly not *heard* by the OP.

Comment: Could you explain me how did you find $\frac{-2aq}{(b^2+g^2)^{3⁄2}}$ from $\frac q{(b^2+g^2)^{3⁄2}}∫_{+a}^{-a} dc$ and also what would be the answer if there was no limit?

Comment: Well, not sure what the comment asks for, but, for **every** $u$ and $v$, one has $$\int_u^vdc=v-u,$$ right? Hence $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dc=+\infty.$$

Comment: That was the answer to my question. Thanks and also what would be the answer if there was no limit in this question?

Comment: No limits $\ne$ limits $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. With limits $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, the result is $+\infty$ if $aq\gt0$, $-\infty$ if $aq\lt0$ and $0$ if $aq=0$.

Comment: That wasn't my question. I asked what would be the answer if the question was $$
q∫_{+a}^{-a}\frac 1{(b^2+c^2)^{3⁄2}} dc
$$

Comment: $$\frac{-2aq}{b^2\,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$